# Erro em Adicionar o IIS no windows 7

Tags: windows, iis

Estou tentando adicionar o IIS 10.0 no meu Windows 7 Ultimate(64x), porém quando vou em Ativar e desativar Recursos do Windows e aparece escrito na tela Aguarde...
porém depois me retorna uma tela totalmente branca sem pode adicionar o IIS

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você provavelmente já tem IIS instalado e/ou seu Windows não tem o Service Pack 1 instalado.

Comment: Até tem uma pasta IIS, mas eu quero acessar o Gerenciador IIS, e me falam que tem que ir nessa tela para pode ativar e pode acessar o Gerenciador do IIS, para assim eu pode publica meu site

Comment: Realmente é nessa tela que você habilita os pacotes do IIS. O estranho é ela estar aparecendo assim...

Comment: @MárcioCristian Isso que acho estranho, o problema que preciso libera ele para pode publica meu projeto em asp.net, a questão que não sei oque pode ser, meu windows não é pirata

Comment: @GuilhermePadovam olha, fiquei curioso em relação a isso... Tenta realizar os passos desse link https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_other-update/windows-7-resource-monitor-not-working-no-data/bf2b3275-e543-4f68-982b-af6695fc3d3d?page=3&auth=1 e me retorna se funcionou ou não, to curioso rsrsr

Comment: @MárcioCristian Por enquanto fiz 3 metodos que diz para fazer e não se resolveu nada

Comment: @GuilhermePadovam teve situações que os usuários conseguiram resolver mudando a resolução dos itens...
"Click on desktop Personalize
Click on Display menu and  change back size items to 100% (default)
it worked fine for me .."

Comment: @MárcioCristian qual metodo seria esse dai?

Comment: To achando que o problema pode ser no meu windows update, não ta atualizando nada do windows

Comment: @GuilhermePadovam, esse seria uma solução que um usuário encontrou. Basta ir em Painel de Controle\Aparência e Personalização\Vídeo e por em   Menor (100%).

Answer (score 1):

Tente assim, digite no menu iniciar `cmd`, clique com o botão direito sobre ele e selecione a opção `Executar como Administrador`.
Digite o seguinte comando:
ServerManagerCMD.exe -install Web-Server -allsubfeatures

De <kbd>Enter</kbd> para confirmar.

Pode ser que ele considere o método obsoleto, mas vai iniciar da mesma maneira, aparecendo assim:

```
...
Start Installation...
<0/100>
```

No final terá que aparecer um relatório de todos os serviços habilitados e pra encerrar:

**Success: Installation succeeded**

Se quiser por PowerShell:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TSS8HYp3L4E

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda Old, mas tive que formatar a maquina, descobri que tinha tanta DLL corrompida que não tinha jeito